# Releasing a program

Tags: c++, windows, c++11

So I made a c++ console game. Now I'd like to "release" the game. I want to only give the .exe file and not the code. How do i go about this. I'd like to make sure it will run on all windows devices.
I used the following headers-

- iostream
- windows.h
- MMSystem.h
- conio.h
- fstream
- ctime
- string
- string.h
  *I used namespace std
  *i used code::blocks 13.12 with mingw

& I used the following library-

- libwinmm.a

Thank you in advance
**EDIT**
[image: This is what happens in depends]

Comment: Just curious, why are you using `conio.h`?

Comment: build and zip the exe?

Comment: Really ALL windows devices?

Comment: The headers you used are mostly irrelevant. You mostly want to use something like [`depends.exe`](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what your program needs to run.

Comment: [support all the windows!](http://www.vintagecomputing.com/wp-content/images/pcworld/windows31_anniversary_small.jpg)

Comment: @shuttle87 conio.h is for getch()

Comment: @perencia I meant all pcs running on windows sorry :P

Comment: @JerryCoffin what do I do with depends.exe

Comment: @Diego Yeah, but should i include headers and libraries in the zip?

Comment: @DevangJayachandran: you point it at the program you want to release, and it'll tell you the DLLs (and such) upon which your program depends.

Comment: @DevangJayachandran you may just want to compile your program statically.  Add the `-static` keyword to your compile line.

Comment: @DevangJayachandran - You do not need the headers. Just the exe and any DLLS/config files

Comment: Note that later versions of Visual Studio do not support Windows XP.

Comment: Perhaps look into wix.(http://wixtoolset.org/)

Comment: @EdHeal Do i need the libraries? And what are the usually required dll's and am i adding any? TY

Comment: @JerryCoffin I tried depends. Didn't understand. would you please look at the screenshot. TY

Comment: You need the DLLs - Useful tool is dependency walker - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/256872

Comment: Create a VM, install a brand new Windows on it and give it a try runnig your app. You'll see what's missing.

Comment: Seems a lot of effort. You do not need a new VM. side-byside should suffice

Comment: Guys I encountered a new problem. When i try to build a release then the .exe doesn't function properly, only the debug version works correctly. why is that?

Comment: wait scratch that. I forgot to initialize some class variables in the default constructor. My Bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways of installing applications. You could go with an installer like [Inno](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) or just go with a regular ZIP file. Some programs can even be standalone by packaging all resources within the executable, but this is not an easy option to my knowledge for C++.

I suppose the most basic way is to create different builds for different architectures with static libraries and then find any other DLLs specific to that architecture and bundle it together in one folder. Supporting x86/x86-64/ARM should be enough for most purposes. I do know that LLVM/Clang and GCC should have extensive support for many architectures, and if need be, you *should* be able to download the source code of the libraries you use and then compile them for each architecture you plan to support as well as the compilation options you need to compile to each one.

A virtual machine can also be helpful for this cross-compilation and compatibility testing.

**tldr; Get all the libraries you need in either static or dynamic (DLL) format. Check that they are of the right architecture (x86 programs/code will not run on MIPS and vice versa). Get all your resources. Get a virtual machine, and then test your program on it. Keep testing until all the dependency problems go away.**

Note: when I did this, I actually had some compatibility issues with, of all things, MinGW-w64. Just a note; you may need some DLLs from MinGW, or, if you're using Cygwin, of course you need the Cygwin DLL. I don't know much about MSVC, but I would assume that even they have DLLs needed on some level if you decide to support an outdated Windows OS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man! I tried inno and it works! ^_^ On my pc .. I'm yet to try on a virtual machine.. and will do so as soon as i get a .iso file for an OS.